# Using Python ARMA model fit

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a time series data and I am trying to fit ARMA(p,q) model to it but I am not sure what 'p' and 'q' to use. I came across this link [enter link description here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.fit.html)

The usage for this model is [enter link description here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma.html)

But I don't think it automatically decides what 'p' and 'q' to use. It seems like I need to know what 'p' and 'q' is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do a bit of reading outside of the statsmodel package documentation.

See some of the content in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12361198/6923545

There's a guy named Rob Hyndman who wrote a great book on forecasting and it would be a fine idea to start there. Chapters 8.3 and 8.4 are the bulk of what you're looking for

#### From Rob's book [chapter 8.3](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/3),

> In an autoregression model, we forecast the variable of interest using a linear combination of past values of the variable.

This is describing *p* -- the number of past values used to forecast a value

#### From Rob's book [chapter 8.4](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/4),

> a moving average model uses past forecast errors in a regression-like model.

This is describing *q*, the number of previous forecast errors in the model.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/auto_data_analysis/estimate_stochastic_processes/plot_estimate_arma.html#sphx-glr-auto-data-analysis-estimate-stochastic-processes-plot-estimate-arma-py) gives you a little bit of theory and some examples.

CASE 1: you already know the values of p and q (orders of the ARMA Model), and the algorithm finds the best coefficients

CASE 2: if you don't know them, you can specify a range of possible values and the algorithme finds the best model ARMA(p,q) that fits to the data and estimates the corresponding coefficients.